# Windows PE 3.0 detect what device it was booted from

Tags: windows-7, batch, script

I am creating a custom boot disk for work using Windows PE 3.0.  I need to be able to tell what drive the system was booted from.  it may be a CD, or a USB Flash drive.  In the past, I have looked for a file on the root of the drive that holds some of our custom configuration.  however that is getting a bit messy.

Basically, in addition to Windows PE, the drive or disk also has other scripts and tools.  I need to remount that USB drive or DVD to the U:\ Drive, to keep thing consistent.

Basically,

```
Diskpart.exe
Select Volume $X
assign Letter=U
Exit
```

I just need to figure out how to determine that nasty little $X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my debate of whether this belonged here or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), I found an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721755/how-can-i-detect-the-drive-letter-of-a-booted-usb-drive-from-script/759531#759531) on StackOverflow (that was never marked as being the answer, but it works perfectly for me!

Right now, I scan a bunch of drive letters, looking or a config file, this will shorten the code drastically!
Basically, query the registry in PE for HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PERamDiskSourceDrive

I figured I'd answer it all here as well, so others scouring the internet can find it better..

***Edit:*** for those searching for the same thing, I added this to my startnet.cmd in windows\system32 in windows PE:

```
REM Get Boot Drive from WinPE Registry
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\system\currentcontrolset\control /v PEBootRamDiskSourceDrive ^| find /i "PEBootRamDiskSourceDrive"') do set driveLtr=%%b 
REM Setup text file on ram drive to pass to diskpart commands
SET MountScript=X:\MountScript.TXT
ECHO SELECT VOLUME %driveLtr% > %MountSCRIPT%
ECHO assign letter=U noerr >> %MountSCRIPT%
DISKPART /S %MountSCRIPT%
REM Don't really need to cleanup, since its a ramdisk, but trying to be nice
DEL %MountSCRIPT%
```

Comment: If the said registry key does not exist, that is because you have to call `wpeutil UpdateBootInfo`.

Comment: I have a refined version of the first part here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/759531/6306782

Comment: I tried to simplify the for statement: `@for /f "tokens=3 delims=    " %%A in ('reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control /v PEBootRamDiskSourceDrive') do @set bootdrive=%%A`

Comment: This value seems to be not available when booting from ISO CD! Works when booting from disk!?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do the following:

```
:: Is 'C' assigned to the boot drive?
if EXIST c:\windows\system32\startnet.cmd (
    echo select volume c > x:\reassignUSB.txt
    echo assign letter=d >> x:\reassignUSB.txt
    echo|set /p=Reassigning USB letter...& diskpart /s x:\reassignUSB.txt >nul
)
```